# How to prevent jquery click events from disabled paper-button

Tags: jquery, polymer

I'm porting my web app from bootstrap+jQuery to Polymer+jQuery, lots of codes of my app handle click event like this:

```
$("#my-button").on("click", function() ...)
```

*#my-button* is a tag BUTTON or A, click event will not fire when it has a *disabled* class when I was using bootstrap.

Now, Polymer use a *disabled* attribute instead of "disabled" class to disable a paper-button, the "click" event will be fired even it actually be disabled.
How can I prevent that happen? thanks.

Comment: [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or [**unbind**](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click

Answer (score 1):

After did a research of bootstrap, I found the answer:

```
paper-button[disabled], paper-icon-button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

add it in your css, no pain anymore.

Comment: This is a great solution if you know what browsers you're using but IE10 and below don't support it http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below will automatically take the disabled class.

```
$("#btn").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: your solution likes @Kush Sharma said, needs adding some codes in all event handlers, I still want to a "one change fix all" solution. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery, by checking for class/attribute disabled.

```
$("#my-button").on("click", function(){
if($(this).attr("class") == "disabled")
  return;
....
....your rest of the code here
});
```

If you have already ported to Polymer, replace .attr("class") with your attribute say "data".

Comment: It should work, but I hate to change codes of all my event handlers, I prefer "one change fix all" solution :)